# Redirect vs RedirectMatch

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I am new to this community though have heard a lot about it. So, I am here today to get solution to one of my queries regarding redirect 301 and redirectmatch 301.

I have tried to redirect a 404 page using Redirect 301 something like that

```
Redirect 301 /part1-url http://domain.com/part1-url/part2-url/part3-url.html
```

This rule worked as a nightmare and my destination URL started misbehaving afterwards and a repetitive string of `/part2-url/part3-url.html` get appended to my detination URL which becomes something like -

```
http:// domain.com/part1-url/part2-url/part3-url.html/part2-url/part3-url.html/part2-url/part3-url.html/part2-url/part3-url.html/part2-url/part3-url.html/part2-url&id=part3-url.html&var=part2-url&var2=part3-url
```

I then used RedirectMatch as follows:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/part1-url$ http:// domain.com/part1-url/part2-url/part3-url.html
```

and it started working fine.

I am not able to understand why this happened and how the 2nd one worked.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Formatting guide http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 16):

`Redirect` is *supposed* to redirect all URLs *starting with the string*. Since the URL you redirect to started with that string, naturally you instantly redirected again.

`RedirectMatch` redirects URLs that match a regular expression. You used `$` to explicitly match the end of the URL as part of that. That means that "starting with" is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Though, I redirected one other URL which had matching beginning as the destination URL but it worked fine with Redirect 301. Source URL  which was redirected - http://www.mcraeeng.com/clark-reliance-water 
                                                           Destination URL -   http://www.mcraeeng.com/clark-reliance-water-columns/boiler-trim/products.html

Answer (score 5):

Taken from Apache.

Redirect:

> The Redirect directive maps an old URL into a new one by asking the
>   client to refetch the resource at the new location.
>
> The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a
>   slash. A relative path is not allowed.
>
> The new URL may be either an absolute URL beginning with a scheme and
>   hostname, or a URL-path beginning with a slash. In this latter case
>   the scheme and hostname of the current server will be added.
>
> Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect
>   request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional
>   path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the
>   target URL.

Source: [Apache Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

RedirectMatch

> This directive is equivalent to Redirect, but makes use of regular expressions, instead of simple prefix matching. The supplied regular expression is matched against the URL-path, and if it matches, the server will substitute any parenthesized matches into the given string and use it as a filename.

Source: [Apache RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)